# mockMvc always return 200 status - Test Exception handling with SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, exception, mockmvc

**ReceiptController** endpoint

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public ReceiptOverdue getReceiptById(@PathVariable int id) {
        return receiptService.getReceipt(id);
    }
```

**ReceiptService**

```
public ReceiptOverdue getReceiptOverdue(Integer id) {
        return receiptRepository.findReceiptById(id).map(MGReceipt::toModel).orElseThrow(() -> ReceiptNotFoundException.getException());
    }
```

And the **ReceiptNotFoundException** class

```
public class ReceiptNotFoundException extends ResponseStatusException {

    public ReceiptNotFoundException(HttpStatus status) {
        super(status);
    }

    public static ReceiptNotFoundException getException() {
        return new ReceiptNotFoundException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

when testing manually I get a **404**

```
{
  "timestamp": 1649076257786,
  "status": 404,
  "error": "Not Found",
  "path": "/api/receipt/10"
}
```

But when using **mockMvc** in the Test case I get always 200 status

```
Expected :404
Actual   :200
```

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = ReceiptController.class)
class ReceiptOverdueControllerTest {


    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private ReceiptService receiptService;


    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
    }

    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() {
    }
   
    @Test 
    void whenReceiptNotFoundReturn404() throws Exception {
        var mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(get("/api/receipt/10"))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isNotFound());
    }   
}
```

**BUT** if I throw the exception in the controller the test will pass ! Is there an issue on how I throw the exception in the service ? or the problem is in my mockMvc Test ? Thanks

Comment: Manually you use: "/api/overdue/receipt/10" on mockMvc you use "/api/receipt/10000". They are different endpoints

Comment: It's not that the issue, I've updated my question

Comment: How are you using MockMvc? Can you post more code, specially the annotations you are using in the test class? Probably you are using mocked beans, and in reality you code is not being called.

Comment: @pringi Done ! Infact the other test cases (getAll and getById) works well, I've just an issue when verifying the exception handling

Comment: Theorically it should works ! But it doesn't :)

Comment: You have to throw the exception when(receiptService.getReceiptOverdue(1000)).thenThrow(ReceiptNotFoundException.class); or something similar in your "whenReceiptNotFoundReturn404" test. Using something like BDDMockito, Mockito or other tool.You are mocking the receiptService, so no real method is called. You have to specify the desired behavior.

Comment: Just a bit question ! do you consider such test as a Unit or Integration test ? thks

Comment: Unit Test, because you are mocking the dependencies.

Comment: i think the 404 response you are getting in test case is not the one you are expecting, have u looked at logs to see what's happening to request ? @Smaillns